# Confused over getting GPS location in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, gps

I am really confused over getting GPS location of user. do i have to implement separate logic for GSM and CDMA devices??...besides there are so many modes for getting GPS location(cellsite , stand alone , cell assisted etc). really confused over which criteria to set..and also some networks refuse some modes(e.g. cellsite).

what i really know that autonomous mode works for all. but that cant be used inside buildings , over near tall buildings...so that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Have you read KB articles? http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe?func=ll&objId=800703&objAction=browse&sort=name

Comment: yesy i have gone through it...but the real problem is in choosing the criteria... some networks allow cellsite while some don't..for GSM devices the only option available is autonomous mode which doesnt work inside buildings..so do i have to check for criterias one by one...like first check for cellsite ,then for assisted , and if that too fails then go for Autonomous..

Comment: Is there any other way i can get my current location without using Location API(JSR 179)...like "Cellsite triangulation"...